# data corruption protection using data mirroring

Tags: c, embedded, type-safety

I want to implement data mirroring to avoid data corruption in RAM memory.

I found a useful article about this topic: https://betterembsw.blogspot.com/2014/05/mitigating-data-corruption.html

Now I'm staring to implement the same strategy as described in the link above:

For global data, it's clear for me how to proceed by creating 2 structures, the 1st one contains all global data and the other one contains the same data but inverted. These structures should be declared in 2 different sections.

But for local data and static local data, I don't have a clear idea how to proceed. If I create 2 structures inside a function, the same manner as global data, then how can I choose their sections inside stack?

Do you have any idea how to implement data mirroring for local data and static local data?

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your use-cases. Data-protection and redundancy is rarely (if ever) needed for non-critical data. And non-static local variables are also rarely (if ever) critical. If there is data in a long-running function that needs such protection (static or not) then use your protected memory handler for that data, instead of keeping it as local variables.

Comment: Furthermore, considering you added the `embedded` tag, any type of redundancy will add quite a lot of overhead. And even for modern high-level embedded systems adding such overhead for non-critical data is a waste of resources.

Comment: It is useless approach as you only can know that the data has been corrupted, but you do not know which copy is correct. You may go ahead and have 3 or more copies and check the majority vote. For example if you have 3 copies and one is corrupted you will chech for the two identical and use this one :D

Comment: This is not the solution you think it is.  So you have some _simple_ software and a bug that causes data corruption, and your solution is to write _complex_ software to detect the consequence of the bug.  If you could not write the simple software bug free, making it more complex may only make matters worse,  If this is for a space application where spontaneous bit-flips from cosmic rays are a legitimate concern, then a hardware mitigation such as ECC memory is a more likely solution.  Better to invest in static analysis, and testing IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want it?

If you need it, you will need hardware support, or a compiler that implements the strategy or both, because every write requires a mirroring action and every read requires a verification action.

The mirroring described in the article you refer to is not capable of detecting "bit flips", or, to be more precise, it cannot find *which* copy has a bit flipped, unless you also use an error detection mechanism on the original and the mirror. For example, a bit flip due to heat or cosmic ray can hit any of your copies. This leads again to hardware.